# Function explode simple text file

Tags: php, explode

I have a simple text file (see below).

```
abc|1356243309
zzz|1356239986
yyy|1356242423
```

I want to simply extract all names before |. So the output should look like:

```
abc
zzz
yyy
```

Below is the string I've attempted to use. I've also tried file('visitornames.txt') etc. I'm not sure what im doing wrong :(. Tried a lot of things.

```
$string = file_get_contents('visitornames.txt');
$names = explode('|', $string);
foreach($names as $key) {

echo $key . '"<br/>';

}
```

No errors, but its simply not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use file-function instead of file_get_contents. It returns file as array where every line is own item. Then you can foreach file content array. Variable you are looking for is first part of the line and that's why you can just echo $names[0].

```
$file = file('visitornames.txt');
foreach ($file AS $line) {
    $names = explode('|', $line);
    echo $names[0] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: +1 `file(...)` will create an array with each line an element (no newline).  `file_get_contents` loads the entire file into a single variable (including the line endings).  This is correct but I would change the variable name `$string` to something more meaningful.

Comment: yep file() seems to be the way. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all lines of a file with the `file` function, then take each first part of the explode and assign it to the result:

```
$names = array();
foreach (file('visitornames.txt') as $line)
{
    list($names[]) = explode('|', $line, 2);
}
```

Alternatively there is `SplFileObject` that is similar but you can more easily extend from it:

```
class Names extends SplFileObject
{
    public function current() {
        list($name) = explode('|', parent::current(), 2);
        return $name;
    }
}

$names = new Names('visitornames.txt');

foreach ($names as $name)
{
    echo $name, "<br />\n";
}
```